# Component not being rendered

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I'm trying to build something to learn its concepts.

I have created some react components but can't figure out why my `Post` component aren't being rendered after the JSON request its done successful.

note: the `Posts` and `PostList` components are rendering with no problem.

What am I missing here?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Posts = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="posts">
        <h3>Featured Jobs</h3>
        <PostList />
        <p>More Awesome Jobs →</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var PostList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { posts: [
    ] };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.getJSON('/api/posts', function(results) {
      this.setState({
        posts: results
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    var posts = this.state.posts.map(function(post) {
      return <PostListItem post={post} />;
    });

    return <ul className='post-list'>{posts}</ul>;
  }
});

var PostListItem = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(e) {
    var post_id = this.props.post.id;
    var path = '/api/posts/' + post_id;
    $.getJSON(path, function(post) {
      return <Post title={post.title} location={post.location} description={post.description} />;
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="post-item">
        <li key={this.props.post.id}><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.post.title}</a></li>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Post = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="post">
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <h2>{this.props.location}</h2>
        <p>{this.props.description}</p>
      </div>
      );
  }
});
```

ps: I'm rendering the Posts component through a rails helper, but you can assume it is working fine.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You are rendering DIVs inside an UL. Also, what would expect to happen when returning a Post component in the `$.getJSON` callback function?

Comment: @David Thank you for your reply. I would like to render the Post component over the Posts Component. In other words, to avoid to redirect to the post details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find a way to pass data to `Post` in the ajax callback (returning a component will do nothing). One way would be to use [`setProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops), something like:

```
$.getJSON(path, function(post) {
  Post.setProps(post);
});
```

Note that this can only be done to root-level components (as stated in the docs). Maybe you need to find a more generic way to handle reactive data (Backbone etc).

Comment: Thank you again. Got it to work callind renderComponent with setProps like you have suggested.

Comment: Don't use renderComponent here. That's very anti-React. I'll describe my suggestion in a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* suggest not calling `renderComponent` inside a component like you said you were in another answer. If I totally misunderstood what you were doing though, please ignore me.

I assume you have something like this in `PostListItem`:

```
// handleClick()
$.getJSON(path, function(post) {
  React.renderComponent(Post(post), this.getDOMNode());
});
```

You're going to confuse React this way and if an update ever comes through, you're going to lose that Post.

Instead, leave all rendering to your `render` function, and put branching logic in there.

```
// handleClick()
$.getJSON(path, function(post) {
  this.setState({post: post})
}.bind(this));

// render()
// probably want to have getInitialState return {post: null}
if (this.state.post) {
  return <Post data={this.state.post}/>;
} else {
  // return fallback thing
}
```

Remember, `render` should describe what your component looks like at any given point of time. As soon as you break out of that and start modifying the DOM in other parts of your application/component, you will almost certainly have bugs.

Comment: hi @paul-oshannessy, thank you for your answer, I'm probably doing this in the wrong way like you said, but I don't know how to render a component somewhere that already has another content. I would like to overwrite it with this new content (coming from the ajax). Something like unmount an 'unused' component and render this new one. How should I do this?

Comment: You don't unmount and render a new one, you just describe in `render` what your view should look like based on data. If it should look different, `setState` will in turn call `render` and your view will be updated.

Comment: @paul-oshannessy What I'm just not understanding is the flux of an Application build with React. I mean, I got your answer, but that way the Post component are being rendered inside a PostList Component, what is not my intention.

Comment: Perhaps you could better describe what you actually want your intention is.

Comment: Sure! I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/klebershimabuku/35dc3192188207493081) with the full code for this component with my intention as a comment. Thank you for help me on this :)

Comment: Ah. Yea, you probably want some sort of router. You'll probably also want to move your data fetching and storage out of those components and into a higher point in your application. ie, if PostListItem fetches the full data for a Post, it owns the data and only it's children can really make use of it. But if you have a PostDataStore (not a component) which handles all of the data fetching and storage, you can access that from wherever and change your top level rendering (which is what happens with routers).